# using Google Maps API for Business with a licence

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

If you purchase a Google Maps API for Business licence, how does this change the way that you call  the maps and geocoding v3 APIs?

Getting a business licence increases the limits for maps and geocoding, but what do you have to do to implement the change in your code?  Or is it all done through registering URLs?

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass "client=CLIENT_ID" in the URL when loading an API. This client ID is also tied to certain URLs that you set up to prevent abuse.

More details here: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/premier/guide.html

Answer (score 1):

In addition to adding the client= parameter, you need to:

1. remove the key= parameter
2. for web services (e.g. Geocoding) digitally sign each request. The signature goes in the signature= parameter and needs to be re-compute for every request:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/webservices

Gotcha: *before* signing requests, make sure to URL-encode them, otherwise signatures will be invalidated if anybody else (e.g. the browser) does the URL-encoding after the signature is added:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/webservices/#BuildingURLs